# Incompatible pointer types initializing UINavigationController with an expression of type UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

```
1. UINavigationController *rnc = self.app.window.rootViewController;
```

I get warning Incompatible pointer types initializing UINavigationController with an expression of type UIViewController

```
2. UINavigationController *rnc = (UINavigationController *)self.app.window.rootViewController;
```

The option 1 shows warning "Incompatible pointer types initializing UINavigationController with an expression of type UIViewController" and the option 2 not. Why ? What is a risk if I will not cast like in the option 2 ?

**UPDATED**

What is a risk of casting UIViewController to UINavigationController ?

Comment: @adobels The risk is that `rootViewController` on `window` is not actually an instance of `UINavigationController*` (or subclass) and your app crashes at runtime.   Swift mitigates this issue by requiring casts in a form of `rnc = window.rootViewController as! UINavigationController`.   The "cast" (it isn't really cast) will be checked at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is pretty clear. In case 1 , the `rootViewController` is of type `UIViewController` and you are giving the `UIViewController` instance to the `UINavigationController`.

In case 2, you are making a cast to convert the `UIViewController` to `UINavigationController`,hence the compiler didn't gave any warning.

You should not try to convert `UIViewController` to a `UINavigationController`. They both are different. `UINavigationController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`.

If you want to make your `rootViewController` embedded in a navigation controller, then you should do something like:

```
 YourRootViewController *rootViewController = self.app.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
```